# Extracting information from online job postings

Tags: data-mining, data, feature-extraction

Okay, so I'm trying to build a data set about data science job openings.

I want to extract information about what kind of minimum education level is expected in each job posting and also how much work experience is the company looking for.

Retrieving information such as the job title, company name and location was rather easy, however when it came to simply trying to answer the question of, " How much work experience does this job require? " - I wasn't able to figure out a general solution that I could apply over the whole dataset.

I'm extracting my data from GlassDoor, and they do have a certain template for job postings but I'm still having a hard time figuring out a solution.

I'd be grateful for any help or a nudge in the right direction, maybe I'm just looking at this all wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that not all job postings indicate minimum education levels; some write these under "Knowledge/Experience", while some use "Requirements". So I can't say for sure there's some template/structure to all the job postings.

What I might try doing:

1. Search for qualification-related words. Have a list of (sub)headings to try finding in each job posting (e.g. "Experience", "Requirements", "Qualifications"). Then extract what you need from the subheading.
2. Search for education-related words, e.g. "Bachelors", "PhD", "Degree" etc, then extract the line that contains this information.

Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, looks like I gotta brush up my regex skills. Thanks for the answer though, now atleast I know what my available options are. I'll update my question after I hopefully solve my problem.